# Monitor shows resolution unsupported when trying to install

Tags: resolution

I'm fairly new to Linux and decided to try elementary as the first distro to main, however when trying to install it from an USB drive, I see the elementary logo for a few seconds during which there's options to press e for options and c for command line or enter to continue with the boot, and after that my monitor says unsupported resolution. My monitor is 1920x1080 and uses a VGA connection.

Comment: Try pressing E, pressing TAB, pressing space at the end of the long line of text, and adding `nomodeset` to the boot parameters.